# Plugged in, not charging OR just remove the battery

Tags: laptop, battery

There are other questions regarding the "Plugged in, not charging" mode but I have not seen a comparison between that and simply removing the battery.

My laptop batery goes into the "Plugged in, not charging" mode to conserve battery cycles. Is there any information on how efficient this is compared to removing the battery, in terms of battery life prolongation? If there is negligible difference, i would keep the battery in for convenience (my laptop is connected to mains power 99% of the time)

Comment: In theory keeping it plugged in but not *completely* charged/charging will allow the laptop to keep the battery at a constant level while if you take the battery out it will self-discharge over some length of time (probably a month or so).  I remember reading that Li-ion batteries prefer to be kept at a high charge level and will suffer less discharge fatigue if you keep it there.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know the details of your laptop/battery/charger, various battery types have an optimal store charge - The charge at which it can be stored the longest. This is why rechargeable batteries are never at 100% when you buy them.

Lithium-Ion batteries (which you laptop most likely has) has a store charge of ~40%. If my memory serves me right, this goes for Lithium-Polymer as well. After storing a LiIon battery for a year in room temperature, fully charged, 80% of the batterys capacity can be recovered. However, if left at 40% charge instead, the recoverable charge level comes up to 96%.

Now, going back to your question, if the charger actually tries to keep the charge level around 40% during the "Powered but not charging"-mode, this would be better than removing the battery fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

I think it creates a significant impact, My XPS L502X has been plugged in 99% time for about a year now and I hardly get 15 min of battery life.

One thing I could suggest, for at least Dell laptop, is this great feature to "Turn off Battery Charging", under power options > Dell battery meter. This disables battery charging until next reboot cycle, and this toggle works on the fly. If only I knew about this before.